# How to get last accessed date of a table and the user who accessed the table in db2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a db2 LUW database, i'm able to get last accessed date using last_used column from syscat.tables, i also need the user name or id who is trying to access thsi table. Is there any system table or view that stores this info. If this is not possible, is there any system table or view that stores history of queries executed along with username and time of execution in db2.

Comment: The auditing functionality may be helpful for your needs, or it may be overkill. Db2-luw does not store history of who accesses what, unless auditing is enabled. But you can use monitoring views to see what's happening right now, and use them to populate your own history tables.

Comment: what is the goal ? the audit function can do this, it depend of traffic it can overload the database. if your need is for legal trace, you can look at sqlrelay and some database firewall that offre this function

Comment: @mao I have to do this without auditing, Is there any system table or view that stores query history. I did this in oracle, there was a system view called v$sql which stores sql text and time. I need similar table in db2 LUW.

Comment: @mshabou The goal is to identify table, its last accessed date and user who tried to access the table without auditing. I'm restricted to do this only using system tables and views, I did this in oracle using v$sql table. I'm looking for similar table in DB2 LUW.